# The "Spring XD" xd-shell can't run the hadoop fs ls command, the command returns a java exception

Tags: hadoop, spring-xd

I compiled the latest spring-xd as I needed CDH support. I am able to start the server however when I connect to the server via the xd-shell I try to change a "configuration". Also this is a kerberized cluster, I am not sure how xd will/can handle that.

1st scenario:

1. admin config server --uri http://`testdomain`:10111
2. hadoop config fs --namenode hdfs://nameservice1:8020
3. hadoop config props set hadoop.security.group.mapping=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
4. hadoop config props load hadoop.security.group.mapping
5. hadoop fs ls

### Error message:

```
xd:>hadoop fs ls
-ls: Fatal internal error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:55)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:254)
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.run(FsShellCommands.java:412)
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.runCommand(FsShellCommands.java:407)
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.ls(FsShellCommands.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
        at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.invoke(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:64)
        at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.execute(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:48)
        at org.springframework.shell.core.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:127)
        at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:483)
        at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:157)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:126)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:38)
        ... 40 more
```

---

2nd scenario

alternatively I remove some java opts

run steps 1, 2 from previous scenario

then

1. hadoop config props set hadoop.security.authorization=true
2. hadoop config props set hadoop.security.authentication=kerberos

error below

---

16:50:29,682  WARN Spring Shell util.NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Authorization (hadoop.security.authorization) is enabled but authentication (hadoop.security.authentication) is configured as simple. Please configure another method like kerberos or digest.

Thanks for you assistance - can't wait to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no specific support in XD for running against a secured Hadoop cluster.

Feel free to open a JIRA ticket at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/XD -- this is something we know we will have to address soon.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance a jira has been opened - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/XD-952

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this - we haven't tested with authorization/authentication in the shell for a while - though it is tested as part of the project https://github.com/vmware-serengeti/serengeti-ws

Are you able to perform operations using the standard hadoop file system shell. e.g.

> hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/file1

Comment: xd:>hdfs dfs -ls /user/<user>
Command 'hdfs dfs -ls /user/<user>' not found (for assistance press TAB)

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls /user/<user>
                No encryption was performed by peer.
                No encryption was performed by peer.
Found 13 items
drwxr-x---   - <user> supergroup          0 2013-10-12 20:00 /user/<user>/.Trash
drwx------   - <user> users               0 2013-10-12 21:02 /user/<user>/.staging
drwxr-xr-x   - <user> users               0 2013-10-09 13:48 /user/<user>/_bsp
drwxr-x---   - <user> users               0 2013-09-20 10:22 /user/<user>/examples
drwxr-xr-x   - <user> users               0 2013-10-09 10:46 /user/<user>/input